# Python - Tkinter - Finding the loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

Once again I am stucked.

In a canvas I display 9 images Every 8 rows I add a column. This is only for testing purposes. At the end the images should be hundreds.
I am trying to identify each image with a unique number. In order to do this I have an event which gives me the coordinates of the canvas. And here comes the noobs part. To get this unique number my code is

```
 if x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==448:
        index_bin=0
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==384:
        index_bin=1
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==320:
        index_bin=2
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==256:
        index_bin=3
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==192:
        index_bin=4
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==128:
        index_bin=5
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==64:
        index_bin=6
    elif x_on_grid==0 and y_on_grid==0:
        index_bin=7
    elif x_on_grid==64 and y_on_grid==448: #new column
        index_bin=8
    elif x_on_grid==64 and y_on_grid==384:
        index_bin=9
```

Of course it works perfectly, but it's not scientific at all.
I am trying to reduce all these lines with a loop but I can't get the number needed, only the last one.

Any ideas?

Best

Comment: just so You know but using `canvas.create_stuff` returns an id. so basically say `image1 = canvas.create_image(*args, **kwargs)` will result in `image1` being an integer for example 1 so there is no need to do what You are doing

Comment: Something like `index_bin = (448 - y_on_grid) // 64 + 8 * (x_on_grid // 64)` - you might want to replace some constants by variables to accomodate more images.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille: super!!!

Comment: I'd use tags. When you create an object you can add a tag to it as an identifier. use something like `image-001`. When the user clicks, use the canvas `find_closest` method to determine which object you clicked on and get the object's tag to find out what it's index is.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code

```
import tkinter as tk

def onclick(event):
    print(vars(event))
    nearest = event.widget.find_closest(event.x,event.y)
    nearest_tag = event.widget.gettags(nearest)[0]
    print(nearest_tag)

def drawCircles(c):
    size = 20
    for i in range(100):
        row = i % 10
        col = i // 10
        x1 = (row * size) + 30
        y1 = (col * size) + 30
        c.create_oval((x1,y1,x1+size,y1+size),tags="image_%03d" % i)

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root,width=400,height=400,bg="white")
c.grid()
c.bind("<Button-1>",onclick)

drawCircles(c)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm using circles(ovals) rather than images but the principle is still the same. I draw 100 circles and as I draw then I assign a tag to them in the format `image_?`. When I click on the canvas, the `find_closest` method is used to determine which of the circles is nearest to the click. It then looks up the tag (or tags) of that object and prints it out.

No need for long winded if-elif-else statements.